# In what format are RSA public keys sent over the internet?

Tags: security, rsa

I am currently assuming that the keys are sent like this

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0
FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUpwmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/
3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ51s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Is that correct or is it in some other form

Comment: They are sent in many different formats. There are many standards to choose from. What you have is "PEM" encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo. It is fairly common because it is documented in RFC 5280 and is the primary format supported by Java as well as many other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, they usually use either DER, or PEM, which is Base64-encoded DER. What you have in the question is PEM.

Internally, DER is a subset of [TLV (tag-length-value)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value), with fields that are relevant to RSA keys.

---

UPD: for the record, only public keys are sent over the wire during the SSL/TLS handshake process. There's no security risk in exposing those. SSL/TLS was designed specifically to withstand man-in-the-middle (read: Wireshark-style) attacks.

Comment: So if someone intercepts the transmission with wireshark for example, what they will see is a PEM formatted key?

Comment: What kind of transmission? There's no standard for passing RSA keys over the Internet. Are you talking about SSL/TLS handshake? In that one, private key is never sent.

Comment: Yes in SSL/TLS im assuming the server has to send the cilent its public key if it has no certificate